Tkinter entry text not updated when using .set() (but textvariable is)
I am having trouble setting a default value for a text entry widget in a Python 3.9 tkinter application.
I am using a StringVar as the text variable, and changing it using .set().
I am trying to pre-set the date (and time).
If I do it in a class, the box is empty, even though the value has been changed:
class test:
    def __init__(self, root):
        # Content frame widget
        mainframe = ttk.Frame(root, padding="3 3 12 12")
        mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))
        
        ttk.Label(root, text="Date/Time").grid(
            column=1, row=3, sticky=E, padx=(5, 0)
        )
        self.date_value = StringVar()
        self.date_value.set(datetime.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
        ttk.Entry(root, width=10, textvariable=self.date_value).grid(column=2, row=3, sticky=E)
        print(self.date_value.get())

root = Tk()
test(root)
root.mainloop()


If I do it outside the class it works.
root = Tk()

mainframe = ttk.Frame(root, padding="3 3 12 12")
mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))

ttk.Label(root, text="Date/Time").grid(
    column=1, row=3, sticky=E, padx=(5, 0)
)
date_value = StringVar()
date_value.set(datetime.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
ttk.Entry(root, width=10, textvariable=date_value).grid(column=2, row=3, sticky=E)
print(date_value.get())

root.mainloop()


What's weird is I do sometimes see it work in the first example, when there's some other error in my code that causes a subsequent error it correctly shows with the date filled.
I'm sure I'm missing something very obvious but would love to know what it is!

You aren't keeping a reference to your test object, therefore it immediately gets garbage-collected, and all of the objects referred to only by it (such as your StringVar) get deleted.  (You might still see the value in some error situations, only because the exception that was thrown contains a reference to the object, and therefore keeps it alive.)

It is because the instance of test() is not store in a variable, so it is garbage collected after it is created.
Just assign the instance to a variable:
...
root = Tk()
app = test(root)
root.mainloop()


Amazing, thank you so much. I had followed the example at the end of the TkDocs tutorial which didn't do this - in case it's not obvious I'm very new to using classes in python!

Your case is not totally the same as the linked example because you don't have any class method that bind to an instance of tkinter widget that reference the instance of StringVar().  Note that all the widgets created inside test class are not garbage collected because the masters of those widgets have references to them.
